# I need to change text into woocommerfce checkout page table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change content in a table th via jquery.
My pat

`#post-39 > div > div > div > div.cart_totals > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th`

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#post-39 > div > div > div > div.cart_totals > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th').html('foo');
});
```

HTML IS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td').html('foo');
});
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">
<tbody><tr class="cart-subtotal">
<th>Subtotal</th>
<td data-title="Subtotal"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>&nbsp;2,370.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="shipping">

<th>Shipping</th>

<td data-title="Shipping">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="shipping">

<th>Shipping 2</th>

<td data-title="Shipping 2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="order-total">
<th>Total</th>
<td data-title="Total"><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>&nbsp;2,407.99</span></strong> </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: I think it's `td` not `th`

Comment: mainly `th` is used inside `thead` for table header

Comment: This is woocommerce checkout page, I have not changed any html. they used it like this

Comment: please share your hmtl code

Comment: Please check question HTML ADDED

Comment: I can't see any `th` ???

Comment: <th>Shipping 2</th>

Comment: you are missing jQuery library in your snippet

Comment: after adding jQuery library `$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th').html('foo');` is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > th').html('foo');
```

});

[check it](https://jsfiddle.net/NIHAR_SARKAR/7qhj8f3p/1/)

Comment: In tr there is one th and one td.

Comment: th contains the heading and td contains value, I need to change heading not value

Comment: can u please share us the HTML part ? U might have used wrong selector.

Comment: This is woocommerce checkout page, if you want I can send you the products links to add into cart and then view checkout page you can see everything there

Comment: Please check question HTML ADDED